# Netbeans weird quote behaviors

Tags: netbeans

I've been having trouble with the latest netbeans ruby ide.

Here is the weird behavior:

"|" = my cursor

`some text |here`

I try to add a single quote. Expected:

`some text '|here`

However I get

`some text h'|ere`

It's worse when there is a linebreak:

```
some text here |
    some other text here
```

turns into

```
some text here 
'|    some other text here
```

Am I hitting some weird behavior of netbeans that can be turned off for this? I mean it is insanely annoying.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in netbeans that may not exist anymore, also who uses netbeans nowdays anyways. Ugh poor stupid old me... should have used Vim.

Answer (score 1):

You should file a bug report. Try searching for a duplicate first:
http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/query.cgi or try the latest development version if it is still an issue

Comment: Seems to be since 6.5 already. Its 6.8 as current. I found it still in 6.9 o well. Guess I won't be using netbeans. I love many posts on this topic: "Any helpful feature should have a disable option" to which the netbeans devs say "no".

Comment: hmmh, the bug is strange. I used the ruby IDE since 6.0, I guess, and never saw this behaviour. Which OS are you using? (I am using linux) you could try to disable the some of the code completion features in Options->Language->Code Completion (e.g. I would try insert closing brackets automatically)